# Fastest way(s) to move the cursor on a terminal command line?

Tags: bash, terminal, window

What is the best way to move around on a given very long command line in the terminal?

Say I used the arrow key or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> to get this long command line:

```
./cmd --option1 --option2 --option3 --option4 --option5 --option6 --option7 --option8 --option9 --option10 --option11 --option12 --option13 --option14 --option15 --option16 --option17 --option18 --option19 --option20 --option21 --option22 --option23 --option24 --option25 --option26 --option27 --option28 --option29 --option30 --option31 --option32 --option33 --option34 --option35 --option36 --option37 --option38 --option39 --option40 --option41 --option42 --option43 --option44 --option45 --option46 --option47 --option48 --option49 --option50
```

Now I need to move (starting from the beginning or the end of the line) the cursor to `--option25` to modify something there.

What is the fastest way to get there? What I usually do is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> to get to the beginning and then repeatedly <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> to move forward, word by word (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> to go the end and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> to then go backward). But on a long line that takes too much time. There must be a way to search and jump directly to the part I need to modify, e.g. `option25`?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Since this hasn't been closed yet, here are a few more options.

- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> to open the current line in the editor specified by `$FCEDIT` or `$EDITOR` or `emacs` (tried in that order).
- If you ran the command earlier, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> for a reverse history search and type `option25` (in this case). The line will be displayed. Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to start editing at this point.
- Use history expansion with the `s///` modifier. E.g. `!-2:s/--option25/--newoption/` would rerun the second-to-last command, but replace option25. To modify the last `./cmd` command, use the `!string` syntax: `!./cmd:s/--option25/--newoption/`
  Any delimiter may be used in place of / in the substitution.
- If editing the previous line, you can use quick substitution: `^--option25^--newoption`
- Character search. This was mentioned by Pax, and can be done in regular emacs-mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> for forward search, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> for backward search.

I recommend the second option. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> is really handy and fast, no mucking about with editors, and you see the results before the command is run (unlike the history expansions).

Comment: You mention `Ctrl + r`, which is indeed really useful.  It is probably also worth mentioning that `Ctrl + s` will do a forward search.

Answer (score 263):

To be clear, you don't want a "fast way to move the cursor on a **terminal** command line".
What you actually want is a fast way to navigate over command line in you **shell** program.

[Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) is very common shell, for example.
It uses [Readline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_readline) library to implement command line input. And so to say, it is very convenient to know Readline bindings since it is used not only in bash. For example, gdb also uses Readline to process input.

In Readline documentation you can find all navigation related bindings (and more):
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Readline-Interaction

Short copy-paste if the link above goes down:

Bare Essentials

- Ctrl-b Move back one character.
- Ctrl-f Move forward one character.
- [DEL] or [Backspace] Delete the character to the left of the cursor.
- Ctrl-d Delete the character underneath the cursor.
- Ctrl-_ or C-x C-u Undo the last editing command. You can undo all the way back to an empty line.

Movement

- Ctrl-a Move to the start of the line.
- Ctrl-e Move to the end of the line.
- Meta-f Move forward a word, where a word is composed of letters and digits.
- Meta-b Move backward a word.
- Ctrl-l Clear the screen, reprinting the current line at the top.

Kill and yank

- Ctrl-k Kill the text from the current cursor position to the end of the line.
- M-d Kill from the cursor to the end of the current word, or, if between words, to the end of the next word. Word boundaries are the same as those used by M-f.
- M-[DEL] Kill from the cursor the start of the current word, or, if between words, to the start of the previous word. Word boundaries are the same as those used by M-b.
- Ctrl-w Kill from the cursor to the previous whitespace. This is different than M- because the word boundaries differ.
- Ctrl-y Yank the most recently killed text back into the buffer at the cursor.
- M-y Rotate the kill-ring, and yank the new top. You can only do this if the prior command is C-y or M-y.

M is Meta key.
For Max OS X Terminal you can enable "Use option as meta key" in Settings/Keyboard for that.
For Linux its more complicated.

**Update**

Also note, that Readline can operate in two modes:

- emacs mode (which is the default)
- [**vi** mode](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC22)

To switch Bash to use vi mode:

```
$ set -o vi
```

Personaly I prefer vi mode since I use vim for text editing.

**Bonus**

In macOS Terminal app (and in iTerm too) you can Option-Click to move the cursor (cursor will move to clicked position). This even works inside `vim`.

Comment: I prefer this answer because it gets down the [essence/root/reason behind] how bash keyboard input works(where it comes from), ie Readline.

Comment: In the standard Ubuntu terminal, Meta (M) is Alt+Shift, unless you disable the menu access keyboard shortcuts in which case it is just Alt.

Comment: In Kde in Konsole the Meta (M) is alt key

Comment: Problem is that Meta+F doesn't work if Meta is ALT since ALT gives access to the menu of the program running (in this case terminal). Is there an alternative?

Comment: what is M-f, so you don't use control here so what is it?

Comment: For iTerm, Meta key is not works until set the Preferences > Profiles > Default > Keys > Left/Right option key acts as +Esc

Comment: What does the C represent? This isn't Ctrl or C is it?

Comment: +1 for history and ability to switch between emacs/vi modes. As a note for both emacs and the default keybindings I personally find it easier to say `C-/` (control forward-slash) to undo. Both `C-_` and `C-x C-u` are a tad verbose imo.

Answer (score 48):

Hold down the Option key and click where you'd like the cursor to move, and Terminal rushes the cursor that precise spot.

Comment: You just duplicated my efficiency

Comment: In which environments does this work? I guess in Mac OS only?

Comment: Works on remote ssh linux, even through a jump server.

Comment: However, this did not work with tmux.

Comment: What is the "option key"?

Comment: I've been wanting to figure this out for a long time. Amazed how easy it was and that it wasn't some setting in the preferences I couldn't find

Answer (score 12):

I tend to prefer vi editing mode (since those keystrokes are embedded into my spinal cord now (the brain's not used at all), along with the CTRL-K, CTRL-X from WordStar 3.3 :-). You can use the command line `set -o vi` to activate it (and `set -o emacs` to revert).

In Vi, it would be (ESC-K to get the line up first of course) "`f5;;B`" (without the double quotes).

Of course, you have to understand what's on the line to get away with this. Basically, it's

```
f5 to find the first occurrence of "5" (in --option5).
;  to find the next one (in --option15).
;  to find the next one (in --option25).
B  to back up to the start of the word.
```

Let's see if the emacs aficionados can come up with a better solution, less than 5 keystrokes (although I don't want to start a religious war).

Have you thought about whether you'd maybe like to put this horrendously long command into a script? :-)

Actually, I can go one better than that: "`3f5B`" to find the third occurrence of "5" then back up to the start of the word.

Comment: No need for a script - just hit "v" in vi mode and open the command line in an editor.  You can format the commandline, err, "script" more nicely with newlines, and there's no tempfile needed. :)

So, "v/25" gets you there in 4 chars.

Comment: But then, you need more than the <Enter> key to run it. @dannysauer

Answer (score 11):

Use Meta-b / Meta-f to move backward/forward by a word respectively.

In OSX, Meta translates as ESC, which sucks.

But alternatively, you can open terminal preferences -> settings -> profile -> keyboard and check "use option as meta key"

Answer (score 9):

After running the command once, run `fc`

It will launch `$EDITOR` with the previous command, then you can use your regular editor to modify the command. When you save and exit, the file will be executed.

..but, as Pax said - the command line isn't particularly good for editing absurdly long lines - why not make the command into a script?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to move forward a certain number of words, hit `M-<n>` (`M-` is for Meta and its usually the escape key) then hit a number. This sends a repeat argument to readline, so you can repeat whatever command you want - if you want to go forward then hit `M-<n> M-f` and the cursor will move forward `<n>` number of words.

E.g.

```
 $|echo "two three four five six seven"
 $ M-4
 (arg: 4) echo "two three four five six seven"
 $ M-f
 $ echo "two three four| five six seven"
```

So for your example from the cursor at the beginning of the line you would hit, `M-26 M-f` and your cursor would be at `--option25|` -or- from the end of the line `M-26 M-b` would put your cursor at `--|option25`

Answer (score 4):

using option key and using a click the place you want to place the cursor with mouse or touchpad is you are using Mac build-in terminal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Incremental history searching

in terminal enter:

```
gedit  ~/.inputrc
```

then copy paste and save

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\e[C": forward-char
"\e[D": backward-char
```

all you need to do to find a previous command is to enter say the first 2 or 3 letters and upward arrow will take you there quickly say i want:

```
for f in *.mid ; do timidity "$f"; done
```

all i need to do is enter

```
fo
```

and hit upward arrow command will soon appear

Answer (score 2):

It might not be the fastest, but this need to be here, **some reading about [ANSI cursor movements](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html)**

*ANSI escape sequences allow you to move the cursor around the screen at will. This is more useful for full screen **user interfaces generated by shell scripts, but can also be used in prompts**. The movement escape sequences are as follows:*

```
- Position the Cursor:
  \033[<L>;<C>H
     Or
  \033[<L>;<C>f
  puts the cursor at line L and column C.
- Move the cursor up N lines:
  \033[<N>A
- Move the cursor down N lines:
  \033[<N>B
- Move the cursor forward N columns:
  \033[<N>C
- Move the cursor backward N columns:
  \033[<N>D

- Clear the screen, move to (0,0):
  \033[2J  or \033c
- Erase to end of line:
  \033[K

- Save cursor position:
  \033[s
- Restore cursor position:
  \033[u
```

*(...)*

*Try putting in the following line of code at the prompt (it's a little clearer what it does if the prompt is several lines down the terminal when you put this in): `echo -en "\033[7A\033[1;35m BASH \033[7B\033[6D"` This should move the cursor seven lines up screen, print the word " BASH ", and then return to where it started to produce a normal prompt.*

---

**Examples**:

Move the cursor back 7 lines:

```
echo -e "\033[7A"
```

Move the cursor to line 10, column 5:

```
echo -e "\033[10;5H"
```

Quickly echo [colors codes](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html), to colorize a program:

```
echo -e "\033[35;42m" ; ifconfig
```

Comment: This is about a very different theme than the question!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `M-x shell` in `emacs`. That provides all editing facilities and keystrokes that `emacs` has, so `C-s` can be used to search the text `option25`, for example.

(But I'd still prefer to be in the real terminal shell instead if someone can point me to good search and edit facilities.)

Answer (score 0):

### Use the mouse

Sometimes, the easiest way to edit a commandline is using a mouse. Some previous answers give a command to open your current line in your $EDITOR. For me (zhs with grml config) that combination is `Alt+e`. If you enable mouse in your editor, you can make use of it.

To enable mouse in Vim, add this to your ~/.vimrc

```
set mouse=a
set ttymouse=xterm2
```

If you then want to do a text selection in terminal (instead of passing the mouseclick to vim), hold Shift when you click; this is terminal specific, of course.

Sysadmins should not be afraid of the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

In Cygwin, you can activate such feature by right-clicking the window. In the pop-up window, select *Options...* -> Mouse -> activate *Clicks place command line cursor* -> Apply.

From now on, simply clicking the left mouse button at some position within the command line will place the cursor there.

Answer (score 0):

first:
export EDITOR='nano -m'

then:
CTRL+X   CTRL+E in sequence.

You current line will open in nano editor with mouse enable. You can click in any part of text and edit

then CTRL+X  to exit and y to confirm saving.

Answer (score 0):

I made a script to make the command line **cursor move on mouse click** :

1. Enable xterm mouse tracking reporting
2. Set readline bindings to consume the escape sequence generated by clicks

It can be found on [github](https://github.com/tinmarino/mouse_xterm/blob/master/mouse.sh)

More info on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55437976/2544873)

Will work if `echo -e "\e[?1000;1006;1015h" # Enable tracking` print escape sequences on terminal when clicking with mouse

Answer (score 0):

```
     #!/usr/bin/env bash
     
     #-###--------------------{ Printf Functions }-----------------------------###-#
     # If scroll occur lines numbers will shifted                                  |
     Term="$(tty)" #                                                               |
     Pxy() { printf "\e[${2};${1}H${3}" ;}            # from 0:0; $1 $2 $3"\n"     |
     XY () { printf "\e[${2};${1}H${3}" ;}            # XY 10 10 'Hello World!'    |
     Exy() { echo -en "\e[${2};${1}H${3}" >$(tty) ;}  # from 0:0; $1 $2 echo $3"\n"|
     Line () { printf -v _L %$2s; printf -- "${_L// /$1}"; } # Line "+-*" 10       |
     # Create sequence like {0..(X-1)}                                             |
     Que () { printf -v _N %$1s; _N=(${_N// / 1}); printf "${!_N[*]}"; } # Que 10  |
     #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     function Text_@ () { printf "\e[${2};${1}H${3}${4}" ;} # $1 $2 $3"\n"         |
     #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     function H_line() { local Line=' ' #                                          |
     builtin printf -v Line "%${2:-${COLUMNS:-`tput cols 2>&- || echo "80" `}}s" # |
     echo -e "\033[G\033[2K${Line// /${1:-=}}" ;} #                                | 
     #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
       
     #-###----------------{ Movements Functions no scroll }--------------------###-#
     Linesup () { echo -n ""$'\033['$1'A'"" >$(tty) ;} #                           |
     Linesdn () { echo -n ""$'\033['$1'B'"" >$(tty) ;} #                           |
     #-### ------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     Mrn() { echo -en ""$'\033['${1}C${2}"" >$(tty) ;}  # move right n             |
     Mln() { echo -en ""$'\033['${1}D${2}"" >$(tty) ;}  # move left  n             |
     Mdb() { echo -en ""$'\033['${1}E${2}"" >$(tty) ;}  # move down n begin line   |
     Mub() { echo -en ""$'\033['${1}F${2}"" >$(tty) ;}  # move up n begin line     |
     Mcn() { echo -en ""$'\033['${1}G${2}"" >$(tty) ;}  # move to column          |
     MU=""$'\033[1A'"" MD=""$'\033[1B'"" MR=""$'\033[1C'"" ML=""$'\033[1D'"" #     |
     Beep=""$'\a'"" Back=""$'\b'"" Creturn=""$'\r'"" Nline=""$'\n'"" #             |
     Formfeed=""$'\f'"" Ctabh=""$'\t'"" Ctabv=""$'\v'"" #                          |
     SavePv=""$'\0337'"" RestorePv=""$'\0338'"" #                                  |
     SaveP=""$'\033[s'"" RestoreP=""$'\033[u'"" #                                  |
     #-### ------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     #       echo move up  $1 right $2 $3"\n" no scroll                            |
     Mhy() { echo -en "\e[${1}A\e[${2}C${3}" >$(tty) ;} #                          |
     #       echo move down $1 right $2 $3"\n" no scroll                           |
     Mdy() { echo -en "\e[${1}B\e[${2}C${3}" >$(tty) ;} #                          |
     #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     #-### --------------------{ Clear Functions }-----------------------------###-#
     HomeClear=""$'\033[H\033[2J'""   # move to 0,0 Clear Screen                   |
     ClearS=""$'\033[2J'"" EraseU=""$'\033[1J'"" EraseD=""$'\033[J'"" #            |
     ReturnClear=""$'\033[G\033[2K'"" # move to 0 Clear Line                       |
     ClearL=""$'\033[2K'"" EraseL=""$'\033[1K'"" EraseR=""$'\033[K'""  #           |
     ClearScroolBuffer=""$'\033[3J'""                                  #           |
     #-###-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     
     Test_movements ()
     {
     Line - 40; echo #
     echo "         1         2         3         4"
     echo "123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|"
     { echo -n "1"; Mcn "30" "30\n" ;}
     { echo -n "1"; Mrn "1" "3";  Mcn "30" "30"; Mln "12" "20\n" ;}
     echo "123456789|123456789|123456789|123456789|"
     echo "         1         2         3         4"
     Line - 40; echo #
     }
     Test_movements
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?