# Detect mouse click in bash script

Tags: bash, unix, mouse

I'm wondering how to run a bash script in the background that will do something (i.e. run a script, or a command, or whatever) whenever a user clicks the mouse. I'd like this to continue running even if the terminal is closed. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: can you get your window system to keep accepting input from a closed window? I'd be very surprised if you can. Having an active mouse assumes that there is some process and event-loop in place to accept the input. If you close a window, you have to rely on an outer layer of software to continue processing, and that means to run a script, your outer layer of software will have to know about the script. Maybe you can register it as a right-click event to the parent process (highly  unlikely) before the window closes. And bash scripts don't normally take mouse clicks (IMO). Sorry, but good luck.

Comment: are you talking about a character terminal or X?

Comment: I see two different questions here. For the first, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966903/how-to-get-mousemove-and-mouseclick-in-bash , for the second, see Aamir's answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using X11, you can try `xdotool` to catch mouse events

It would be something like:

```
xdotool search --onlyvisible . behave %@ mouse-click getmouselocation
```

[xdotool manual](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool#mouse_commands)

If you want to run the script in background you can use:

```
./myscript.sh &>/dev/null &
```

Answer (score 4):

if you just want to run bash command in xterm on mouse click (or wheel event) you can try this example:

`$ echo -e "\e[?1000h"`

`$ while read -n 6; do echo hellowworld; done`

this is for wheel event (for click set 12 instead)

Comment: Thank you for finally setting me on the right track! Here is a good reference doc https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html (like ?1000l disables ?1000h)

Answer (score -1):

To keep the script running even when terminal is closed you may try **nohup**.