# Bash script clickable option

Tags: bash

Can I make a bash script mouse clickable?

I have a menu

> Choose your option:
>
> 1. Option 1
> 2. Option 2
> 3. Option 3

I want when i click the option with mouse, it will execute a command.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I don't think it's possible as a general solution, but take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966903/how-to-get-mousemove-and-mouseclick-in-bash

Comment: Your only options are to use a scripting ui like `zenity` or `kdialog` (for X windows). While `zenity` is a gnome app, and `kdialog` is a kdeapp, you can use either on any X display.