# Mouse events in terminal emulator

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, command-line-interface, mouseevent

**Question**

Is it possible, in a terminal emulator, to run a command whenever a mosue event happens?

**What I've tried**

I think I'm halfway there - using `echo -e "\e[?1003h"` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966903/how-to-get-mousemove-and-mouseclick-in-bash) for details) and waving the mouse about over the terminal produces a desirable effect of printing a bunch of characters, related to the occurred mouse event. (Note: `echo -e "\e[?1003l"` turns this off)

```
echo -e "\e[?1003h"
# move mouse over terminal window, in the character input line, NOT to stdout:
> CF*CC+C@,C;.C:/C8/C8/C8/C8/C9/C9/C9/C90C90C80C81C81C81C81C81C90C:/C;/C;.C<.C<.

# After deleting that, I enter:
> echo -e "\e[?1003l"
# mouse move, all is quiet
```

I've also tried hooking it up to output to a file. This was to see if I could watch the file and run a command according to that. It went as follows:

```
> echo -e "\e[?1003h" >> file.txt 
# elevator music whilst I move the mouse about

> echo -e "\e[?1003l"
# move mouse a bit, nothing

> cat file.txt


# nothing but blank lines, fair enough. But, mouse moves and in the terminal input is printed...

> CF*CC+C@,C;.C:/C8/C8/C8/C8/C9/C9/C9/C90C90C8 ...

#  Delete that output, and then I type:
> echo -e "\e[?1003l"
# mouse moves, no output
```

**What I want**

How can I either capture this output so that it is going to `stdout`, or to a file, so that I can then use the changing output to trigger running a command? If that's not possible, is there any other way to capture when a mouse click occurs in a terminal emulator, with the event coordinates?

Comment: Sure - applications can decode mouse-events, but ***whenever*** is too broad...

Comment: Have you considered something like `ncurses`, which would support this sort of thing natively (needs C-programming)?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sylt/93d3f7b77e7f3a881603

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not output, it's input.

There are multiple ways to read input in bash. Here's one that reads everything until stopped:

```
echo -e "\e[?1003h"    
echo "Press enter and then ctrl-d to stop reading"
cat > myfile
```

When done and correctly exited with Enter and Ctrl+D you can inspect `myfile` to see all the mouse events.

A proper mouse application would disable local echo and terminal buffering before reading and decoding the escape sequences from the terminal.