# Capturing Mouse in Virtual Terminal with ANSI Escape

Tags: c, terminal, ansi-escape

I've started to learn about ANSI escape sequences online through the magic of Google. It is neat being able to position the cursor `\e[row;colH` on the screen and set the colors of the outputs (ie: `\e[31m`).

Next I would like try and see how the mouse able to be captured in a virtual terminal. I realize this code is not portable, and I know I can use ncurses or some other curses library, but the goal here is to learn how it works, not write production code with it.

I have tried `\e[?1003h` and it starts to fill the screen with mouse events. (Pretty cool!) However, how do I capture these in a C or C++ program?

I saw an example of what I would like to do in PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58390575/1770034

However, when I try to port the code over to something in C it just locks up in the while loop. (Tested with GDB to find that out.)

```
#include <stdio.h> //bring in printf and fread

int main()
{
    system("stty -echo"); //make the terminal not output mouse events
    system("stty -icanon"); //put stdin in raw mode
    printf("\e[?1003h\e[?1015h\e[?1006h"); //start getting mouse events
    char* buffer[255];
    while(fread(buffer, 16, 1, stdin)) // <-- suppose to read in the mouse events
    {
        printf("here"); //Did you actually work?!
    }
    printf("\e[?1000l"); //Turn off mouse events
    system("stty echo"); //Turn echoing of the display back on
    return 0; //end the program in a successful state
}
```

I have also tried `scanf` and it just locks up until I hit enter, and I'm not convinced it is seeing the mouse events.

**Edit**

I now have some working code that spits out the mouse events.

Here is the updated code from applying the accepted answer to this question:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    system("stty -echo"); //don't show mouse events on screen
    system("stty -icanon");
    fprintf(stderr, "\e[?1003h\e[?1015h\e[?1006h"); //use stderr since not buffered turn on mouse event capture
    char buffer[16] = " ";
    char previousBuffer[16] = " ";

    //Make standard in not be blocking
    int flags = fcntl(stdin->_fileno, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(stdin->_fileno, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

    for (int hunSeconds = 0; hunSeconds < 500; hunSeconds++) //Run for 50 seconds
    {
        read(fileno(stdin), buffer, 16); //read mouse input
        if (strcmp(buffer, previousBuffer) != 0) //only show event if it is different
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s", buffer);
            strncpy(previousBuffer, buffer, 16);
        }
        usleep(100); // sleep for .1 seconds
    }
    printf("\e[?1000l"); //turn off mouse events
    system("stty echo"); //turn on screen echo again
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

- `printf` is (using *stdout*) buffered, so there's no guarantee that the escape sequences got to the terminal before attempting to read.
- *stdin* isn't necessarily the terminal (though it might be).  Again, [`fread` is buffered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584142/what-is-the-difference-between-read-and-fread) (and you may not get the result as promptly as you wish).

Since *stderr* is not buffered, it would help to send the escape sequences with that stream.  Rather than using `fread`, it can help to use `read`, e.g.,

```
read(fileno(stdin), buffer, 16)
```

Comment: or alternatively use `fsetvbuf(file, NULL, _IONBF, 0)`

Comment: `s/fsetvbuf/setvbuf/`

Comment: thanks for remind me lol. i always prefix stuffs that use FILE* with `f`