# How to quickly jump to the beginning of a command on terminal?

Tags: terminal, grep, keyboard-shortcuts

For example:

```
% grep my_words /xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/name.txt
```

When I am the end of the command line, I often need to jump to the beginning, i.e. before grep or after the grep command. I have to move backward character by character, and it's very slow.

How to do that?

Comment: Press Ctrl+A to jump to the beginning of the commnad and  Ctrl+E to the end. Did you try?

Comment: @αғsнιη Ctrl+A and E works. Is there a one button that works?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way(s) to move the cursor on a terminal command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657130/fastest-ways-to-move-the-cursor-on-a-terminal-command-line)

Comment: If you want to move word by word:  Move the insertion point forward one word : Option-Right Arrow.  
Move the insertion point backward one word : Option-Left Arrow.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac you can use the combination:
`ctrl + A`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply click the home key to move the cursor to the start of the command.

Comment: What's the home key on Mac?

Comment: well we can use fn + left key to makes jumps in mac because we don't have a home button on mac. can you check ctrl + A